# multipolygons to one polygon, shortest distance

Tags: sql-server, geometry, gis

I need to find the shortest outer line of multipolygons in MSSQL (2012/ Azure)

From this:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6491751/geopolygons.png

To:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6491751/geopolygons_filled.png

Like you can see a ConvexHull is way too big.
Is this even possible?
And if so, how?
I was thinking about a convexhull between each polygon with its nearest polygon.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely have to look at [alpha shapes.](http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~jgiesen/tch/sem06/Celikik.pdf)

Picture from CGAL page:

[image]

Comment: That looks promising, I'll look into it!